# Need advice on LDOs that can take ceramic caps on Vin (8.4 V) and Vout (5 V) at 50 mA of current draw

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, voltage-regulator, ldo, component-selection

I´m designing a really small circuit based on an ATtiny85 and a laser ranger sensor. The PCB is really small, 30 mm by 20 mm, so I need to use smaller and fewer components.

I need a recommendation for an easy to find LDO that takes a 2S Battery (8.4 V max.) as Vin, 5 V as Vout, 50 mA max. of current draw (it´ll probably draw 25 mA). I need an LDO that can take easy to find ceramic caps on Vin and Vout, maybe in SOT-89 or SOT-23 if it doesn´t heat up a lot in my case.

I´m searching for a model and I came to three options, but then I also got some doubts, and I don´t know which would be a better option for my use.

1. and 2. MCP1702 and MCP1703: Both accept (8.4 V max - 2S) as Vin, and can take ceramic caps. The datasheet says at least 1 μF on Vin and Vout is needed. Should I use the recommended setup? I´ve read that a battery's internal resistance increases as it discharges, so a bigger capacitance on the VIN is better. But how much would be a good value for Vin and Vout? My batteries can´t be let to discharge below 6 V. Also, heat dissipation would be 153°/W. At 50 mA in SOT-89 it´ll heat only 26°C, right?
2. LP2985-5V, also can take ceramic caps, 2.2 μF at least. But how much would be a good value for Vin and Vout caps in my case?

Are these good options? Or are there any other better ones?

** EDIT 1: The laser Ranger Finder is a really small complete module-pcb, so it has it's own small LDO to get from up to 5V VIN down to 2.8V, at which it operates. So the LDO I want will get the 8.4V to 5V, that can supply both the Attiny at 5V and the laser module at 5VIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your laser rangefinder draws pulsed current,

If the rangefinder is powered from 8.4V, then this will be noisy and you need a LDO with decent PSRR.

If it is powered from the output of the LDO, then you need a good transient response so the LDO output voltage does not fall out of spec when it emits a laser pulse.

In any case, micropower LDOs like the two MCPs tend to be quite slow, which means low PSRR and slow transient response, as shown by the datasheet curves. LP2985 has a higher quiescent current, but it is much faster and will provide more stable output with a dynamic load. Datasheet gives an output impedance plot (figure 13) which if nice and flat with 4.7µF output cap.

It would be helpful to know the laser's peak current draw, especially if it is powered from the LDO. Putting numbers on it is always better than handwaving... For example if the laser is powered by the output of the LDO then you must be sure that its peak current (not average current) is lower than the LDO's max output current.

Regarding capacitors, if this is a hobby project, it is always cheaper to buy ceramic capacitors in quantity, which means you buy 100 of a small number of different values. 10µF 16V X5R 0805 costs 3 cents each if you buy them by 100, so there is no point in spending the time to click in the search engine to select a 2.2µF cap, just put 10µF on both sides. Transient response gets better with a larger cap.

Comment: the ranger finder module is a complete mini pcb with it's own small LDO, to get the 5V output from the LDO I want, to power the circuit, down to 2.8V, at which the laser module operates. From the page 36 of the datasheet, it says that the peak instantaneous current is 38mA, and the average current is 8mA. https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vl6180x.pdf

Comment: OK, that's pretty low current, your choice of LP2985 should be OK. You could run the micro at 3V3 too. What are you using for voltage translation?

Comment: Thanks! The Rangefinder module has already 10K pullups on the sda and scl lines to chosen VIN (in my case 5V, but could also be 3.3V). So no need of external level shifters.

Comment: This one? https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4000051739651.html OK it has MOSFETs for voltage translation, it's fine

Comment: Actually is this one..  But it seems that there's only one mosfet..  Is that a problem? I've been using it for some time at 5V and it's been working with no problems...  https://a.aliexpress.com/_mNZrYzG

Comment: The tiny 6 pin chip should be the dual MOSFET for I2C voltage translation and the 3 pin SOT23 should be the LDO.

Comment: You’re completely right! I checked the components! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Digikey has almost 700 models in stock matching that spec, most of which are in packages at least as small as SOT-23.  Since there isn't a lot special about your needs, and this is about the most generic possible part, price is probably a major factor.

Regarding capacitors, you need large enough to be stable, which should be specified in the datasheet. Since your current draw is very low, making them larger won't make much difference, but you can go larger if you're worried about it.